# web spidering/crawling, can i do it or just search engines?

Tags: website, wget, web-crawler

i already had a question answered about web-scraping with wget. but as i read a little more, i realize i may be looking for a web-crawling program.  particularly the part about web-crawlers being able to get specific data like links or, in my case, products.
all of the products on my site have the following naming convention, website.com/uniqueAlphaNumericID.html
as far as i know, no dynamic content generation is being used and only one page per one item in the above format.
should i just be thinking about:
wget website.com | grep *.html
or should i be looking into spiders/crawlers?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: can i use a web-spider program myself on a web-page, or is this terminology used for only the search-engine itself getting data from pages? can i use a web-crawler program on mac osx, or any other OS for that matter and what is one you would recommend? what i am trying to do is find different ways to pull data from a website